# Como proceder quando uma resposta não tem nada a ver com a pergunta?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, respostas-erradas

Na pergunta [Erro de memória em cruzamento de tabelas muito grande em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/542322/erro-de-mem%C3%B3ria-em-cruzamento-de-tabelas-muito-grande-em-python), a única [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/542341/275701) dada até agora não tem absolutamente nada a ver com o que foi perguntado. É claramente um erro do respondedor, que talvez achasse que estava com a página de outra pergunta aberta e se enganou.

Eu sinalizei a resposta como "qualidade muito baixa", mas fiquei na dúvida sobre o procedimento adequado nessas situações. Notei que existem comentários padrão, mas a resposta não tem qualquer chance de salvação.

Comment: É sim, mas também pode usar o downvote, pois o sistema de votos é justamente para isso, avaliar a qualidade da postagem, se ela tem problemas o downvote é totalmente justo.

Comment: No caso, não tenho reputação suficiente para votar. Até lá, nesses casos eu sinalizo. Obrigado!

Comment: Então a flag que fez esta correta, qualidade baixa, você também pode comentar, eu acabei de questionar o AR (autor da resposta): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/542322/erro-de-mem%C3%B3ria-em-cruzamento-de-tabelas-muito-grande-em-python#comment973452_542341

Comment: Eu pensei que este questionamento era sobre esta [postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/542253/103217)